# azure mobile api variable scope

Tags: node.js, express, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have the following Azure Mobile Services API get function. I want to set the isValidUser flag based on if there is a record for the providerKey (from the twitter authentication) in the SQLMembership table (AspNetUserLogins).

While testing, I see the following in the log file, confirming that the flag is being set.
"setting isValidUser [object Object] Number of records = 1"

However, if(isValidUser) is not getting evaluated correctly. The result I get from the API is "Not a registered user." which is set from the else portion of the if(isValidUser) check.

Why is it that the value set inside the mssql.query() is not available outside of it?

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var authenticatedUserId = request.user.userId;

    var providerName = authenticatedUserId.split(":")[0];
    var providerUserId = authenticatedUserId.split(":")[1];
    var isValidUser = false;


    console.log('providerName = ' + providerName.trim());
    console.log('providerUserId = ' + providerUserId.trim());
    request.service.mssql.query(
        "select userId from dbo.AspNetUserLogins where LoginProvider = '" + providerName + "' and ProviderKey = '" + providerUserId + "'",
           {
                success: function(results)
                {
                    console.log('inside success AspNetUserLogins. ' + results + " Number of records = " + results.length);
                    if (results.length == 1) {
                        console.log('setting isValidUser ' + results + " Number of records = " + results.length);
                        isValidUser = true;
                    }
                },
                error : function(err)
                {
                    console.log('inside error AspNetUserLogins. ' + err);
                    response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, { error: err });
                }
            }
        );
    if (isValidUser) {
        request.service.mssql.query('select * from dbo.Church',
            {
                success: function(results)
                {
                    console.log('inside success Church' + results);
                    response.json(statusCodes.OK, results);
                },
                error : function(err)
                {
                    console.log('inside error : ' + err);
                    response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, { error: err });
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, { error: "Not a registered user." + isValidUser });
    }

    response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, { error: "Unexpected end." });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `mssql.query` is an asynchronous function (like many other functions in node.js); when it returns the callback (either the success or the error) hasn't been executed yet, so when you check the `isValidUser` flag, it still has the original value (false).

What you need to do is to move that code to inside the success callback, and that should work:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var authenticatedUserId = request.user.userId;

    var providerName = authenticatedUserId.split(":")[0];
    var providerUserId = authenticatedUserId.split(":")[1];
    var isValidUser = false;


    console.log('providerName = ' + providerName.trim());
    console.log('providerUserId = ' + providerUserId.trim());
    var sql = "select userId from dbo.AspNetUserLogins where LoginProvider = ? and ProviderKey = ?";
    var sqlParams = [providerName, providerUserId];
    request.service.mssql.query(sql, sqlParams, {
        success: function(results)
        {
            console.log('inside success AspNetUserLogins. ' + results + " Number of records = " + results.length);
            if (results.length == 1) {
                console.log('setting isValidUser ' + results + " Number of records = " + results.length);
                isValidUser = true;
            }
            if (isValidUser) {
                request.service.mssql.query('select * from dbo.Church', {
                    success: function(results)
                    {
                        console.log('inside success Church' + results);
                        response.send(statusCodes.OK, results);
                    },
                    error : function(err)
                    {
                        console.log('inside error : ' + err);
                        response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, { error: err });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, { error: "Not a registered user." + isValidUser });
            }
        },
        error : function(err)
        {
            console.log('inside error AspNetUserLogins. ' + err);
            response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, { error: err });
        }
    });
};
```

One more thing: do use parameters in the SQL (also shown above), instead of composing the query directly. In this case (you're using the user id) it shouldn't be a problem, but as a general rule you should use parameters whenever possible to prevent SQL injection attacks.